# Having trouble moving image files from the temporary file to permanent folder on server

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

I have no problem uploading information from my html form into my database, but I can't get images to show up. I think it has to do with the fact that I can't properly move the image file from the temporary file to the permanent file on the server (which would mean that my $imgURL variable is holding the wrong information I guess?) but I can't figure it out.

UPDATE: I can now upload an image to a temporary location (see picture.js below) but for some reason, the image won't pass on to its final destination. I get a "No File" error code when I try to send the image from the temporary file to its final destination folder. Any ideas as to why that might be?

Thank you!!

This is my upload_func.php file:

```
<?php

    $upload_errors=array();

    function file_upload($fileKey, $uploadDir){

        global $upload_errors;

        $error_code=null;
        $desc=null;
        $imgURL=null;
        $info=array();

        if(($_FILES[$fileKey]["type"]== "image/gif")||($_FILES[$fileKey]["type"]=="image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES[$fileKey]["type"]== "image/jpg")|| ($_FILES[$fileKey]["type"]== "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES[$fileKey]["type"]== "image/x-png")||($_FILES[$fileKey]["type"]== "image/png")
        && ($_FILES[$fileKey]["size"]< 3000000)){

            if($_FILES[$fileKey]["error"]>0){
                $error_code=$_FILES[$fileKey]["error"];
                $desc=$upload_errors[$error_code];
            }
            else{

                $uploaded_file = $_FILES[$fileKey]["name"];
                $tmp_file=$_FILES[$fileKey]["tmp_name"];
                $imgURL = $uploadDir.basename($uploaded_file); //http://129.2.24.54/ckmayo/geog650/lab3/uploads/1.jpg

                if(file_exists($uploaded_file)){
                    $error_code = -2;
                    $desc = "File already exists";
                }
                else{

                    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $imgURL)){
                        $error_code = 0;
                        $desc = "File uploaded successfully";
                    }
                    else{
                        $error_code = $_FILES[$fileKey]['error'];
                        $desc = $upload_errors[$error_code];
                    }
                }           
            }
        }
        else{
            if($_FILES[$fileKey]['error']>0){
                $error_code=$_FILES[$fileKey]['error'];
                $desc=$upload_errors[$error_code]; //$upload_errors is a global variable
            }
            else{
                $error_code = -1;
                $desc = "File upload error: Invalid file";
            }
        }


    $info["code"] = $error_code;
    $info["desc"] = $desc;
    $info["imgURL"] = $imgURL;
    return $info; 
    }   
?>
```

Here's my picture.js file where I send my picture to a temporary location:

```
var imgURI;
var serverURL="http://geogthemis001.umd.edu/elim/geog650/lecture4/upload.php";

$(document).ready(function(){
    //attach a event handler function to the deviceready event using document.addEventListener()
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", getCameraReady, false);
});

//function onDeviceReady(){
    //getCameraReady(); 
//}

function photoSuccess(uri){
    $("#img").attr("src", uri);
    $("#img").css("width", "100%");
    $("#img").css("height", "100%");

    imgURI = uri;
}

function photoFail(message){
    alert("ERROR: "+ message);
}

function uploadSuccess(result){
    alert("File Upload Done");
    navigator.camera.cleanup();
    alert("Sent: "+ result.bytesSent + " \nResponse: "+ result.response);

}

function uploadFail(error){
    alert("An error has occured: Code " + error.code);
}

function getCameraReady(){
    $('#btCamera').on('click',function(e){

        options={quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA};       
        navigator.camera.getPicture(photoSuccess, photoFail, options);

    });

    $('#btPhotoLib').on('click',function(e){

        options={quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY};     
        navigator.camera.getPicture(photoSuccess, photoFail, options);

    });

    $('#btUpload').on('click',function(e){
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = imgURI.substr(imgURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg"; //how to get the mime type of data

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        var server = encodeURI(serverURL);
        //alert(imgURI);
        ft.upload(imgURI, server, uploadSuccess, uploadFail, options);

    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to move them to a url and not to a folder? Are they supposed to be on a different server?

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry I didn't notice your comment before. Hopefully my updated code answers your question, I am trying to move it to a folder on a server.

Comment: Don't move files to a URL, especially when it's on the same server that you've uploaded them to.... use filesystem references, not web references

Comment: Could you clarify: what's the difference between a filesystem reference and a web reference?

Comment: Your webserver root is (for example) `/var/www` within the filesystem (as defined in your webserver configuration): this is the document root. So URL (or web reference) `http://129.2.24.54/` is pointing to folder `/var/www` in the filesystem; URL `http://129.2.24.54/ckmayo` is pointing to folder `/var/www/ckmayo` in the filesystem, etc. For most of PHP's filesystem functions, it is generally best to work with filesystem paths rather than URLs

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you're trying to move your image to an URL and it makes no sense...

Have you try to replace (in the move_uploaded_file call) the variable `$imgURL` by `$uploaded_file` ?

You should try with :

`if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $uploaded_file)){`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I made the edit but I'm still not seeing my image file anywhere.

Comment: Ok, but what is the image that your browser try to load (the url built) ? Have you checked in your HTML generated ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: You've said "I'm still not seeing my image file anywhere" : so, where are you checking the image file ? Through the browser ? Anyway, there is no file in your "http://129.2.24.54/ckmayo/geog650/lab3/uploads/" so I suppose the `move_uploaded_file` doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm expecting to see it in my uploads folder on the server. I suppose I thought I would see it in my database as well, but I'm pretty sure it should at least be on the server. The URL there is supposed to connect to the folder on my server

Comment: Yes and no. I think I figured out my issue with move_uploaded_file, but I still can't get the image to it's final destination. I can upload the picture to a temporary location, though.